# Flutter FireStore: Unable to reverse a firebase snapshot list

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a chat app using firebase and flutter. When i type a msg the order of the message appearing is random. I want the messages to appear by timestamp. I am really new to coding. Can someone help me out?

For ex:
I just typed-[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE5BY.png)

And the messaged just appeared at some random place-[Should have appeared after last message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSS9N.png)

Here's the code:-

```
class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data!.docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message['text'];
          final messageSender = message['sender'];

          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender!,
            text: messageText!,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );

          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }

        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
    );
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageBubble({
    super.key,
    required this.sender,
    required this.text,
    required this.isMe,
  });

  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            elevation: 5,
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                  )
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
            color: isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 15,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried .reverese but didn't work!
final messages = snapshot.data!.docs.reversed;

But it didn't work. I am really new to this, Please help me on this stackoverflow gods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a timestamp field to your messages and then use the .orderBy() method in your query to get the latest messages.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

The timestamp field can either be a DateTime or an int.

### DateTime

This way is a little more involved but it let's you directly use the DateTime type in your code.

1. Create a DateTimeConverter

```
class DateTimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime?, Timestamp?> {
  const DateTimestampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime? fromJson(Timestamp? timestamp) => timestamp?.toDate();

  @override
  Timestamp? toJson(DateTime? dateTime) => dateTime != null ? Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime) : null;
}
```

2. Install the [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package.
3. Annotate your message class with the @JsonSerializable annotation

```
part 'message.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
  converters: [DateTimestampConverter()],
)
class Message {
  String id;
  ...


factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MessageFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MessageToJson(this);

}
```

4. Run the build runner

`flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

## Int

Alternatively, save the timeCreated field as an int like this:

```
Message newMessage = Message(
timeCreated: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
)
```

Comment: I tried but i am unable to store the timestamp value from flutter to firebase timestamp. it say 'timestamp cannot be int'

Comment: Please show the code that creates this error in your question. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).